# Pivot off of access query is misbehaving

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, pivot-table

So I have a document that has a pivot table that was previously linked to an access query. It worked fine, no issues. The problem started when I wanted to change which database the pivot table was linked to. When I tried to change the external data source to the new database, excel gave me the "cannot complete the task with available resources" error. I find this error can be a little finnicky so I tried deleting the pivot and creating a new pivot with the link I want, except now the pivot comes up empty. It pulls in the column headers (in the pivot editor thing) but no data comes up when I add fields to the pivot. I should also add that the new database is exactly the same as the old one - the only difference is a new column of data.

Any thoughts? This is driving me crazy. It might be that the results from access are too big for excel to process, but I've been paring down the results and none of it makes a difference.

Comment: This might be overstating the obvious, but have you 1) done a compact and repair on your database and 2) closed Access completely and reopened the compacted DB before re-running your process?  How large is the database, and how many rows are being pivoted?

Comment: I did 1 and 2. The database is ~ 1.4Gb, and when I converted the select query into a create table query and pivoted off of the resulting table it worked...